# How to make proxychains work as transparent proxy server

Tags: networking, linux, proxy

my proxychains is configured to use several proxy server and it work fine in local-host, but i need to route all traffic of other host's to routed through proxychains-host! something link this:

```
my-host <> proxychains-vm <> proxy1 <> proxy2 <> proxy3 <>...<> proxyN <> google.com
```

All i need that is somehow route all internet traffic of my Lan network pass via several private proxy server

Comment: Hello and welcome to Security.SE! I'm voting to migrate this, as it is not an information security question. Your end goal is definitely possible, but it is going to be quite a bit more complicated than you might expect.

Comment: sorry if i ask in wrong place, before here i was asking in tour exchange and someone offer me to ask here! i'm new with hole community so please accept my apologies - i know there is no easy solution and also i do this in some temporary way but  i need the proper and stable way to do that. so please if u can just guide me in right way
tnx

Comment: Well, proxychains isn't really designed for this; as you may have noticed, it's basically run as a wrapper around other programs. So, you could either 1. Modify the source code to do what you want, or 2. Use proxychains to run a proxy server, so all connections outbound from the fake proxy server will go through proxychains.